# expanding a square openCV

Tags: java, opencv, coordinates

I am trying to expand a rectangle with given persentage using openCV. I wrote a function for it below. Since x and y values of Rectengle class are [public](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Rect.html#x), I must have get and set x and y values without using getter or setter methods(The class does not have them though). However I get a NullPointerException error on the line "temp.x=r.x-(tempWidth/2);" during debugging.

What would be the problem ?
Thanks

```
  public Rect extendRect(Rect r,double persent,int bmpWidth,int bmpHeight)
   {

    Rect temp = Rect(0,0);
    int tempWidth =(int)(r.width*persent+(double)r.width);
    int tempHeight =(int)(r.height*persent+(double)r.height);
    temp.x=r.x-(tempWidth/2);// orginal rect 
    temp.width=tempWidth;

    temp.y=r.y-(tempHeight/2);
    temp.height=tempHeight;
    //boundary check
    if((temp.x+temp.width)>bmpWidth)
    {
        temp.width = bmpWidth-temp.x;
    }
    if(temp.x<0)
    {
        temp.x=0;
    }
    if((temp.y+temp.height)>bmpHeight)
    {
        temp.height =bmpHeight-temp.y;
    }
    if(temp.y<0)
    {
        temp.y=0;
    }

return temp;

 }
```

Comment: dont you have to give some width and height to the constructor? `Rect temp = Rect(0,0, width, height);`

Comment: You are right. Because compiler (eclipse) did not give any error I thought It was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Rect temp = Rect(0,0);
```

This line should be

```
Rect temp = new Rect(0,0);
```

Actually this shouldn't even compile. Just use

```
Rect temp = new Rect();
```